# How to arrange the data in alphabetical order in C?

Tags: c

In this code, the data is not arranged after swaping. It is giving me the same result as it is text in file. This means without any alphabetical order.

**Text in file**

```
Bilal Khan,1111111111111
Ali Ahmed,2222222222222
hello,3333333333333
darth,4444444444444
```

**Expected output**

```
Arrangement of data in alphabetical order.
```

**Result showing**

```
Without any change the data from the file appearing the same.
```

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STRING_LEN 200

int main(){
  char string[STRING_LEN], first[5][20], s[10];
  FILE* fp1 = fopen("file.csv", "r");
  char* data;
  int i = 0, round, number=0, r;

  for(number=0; ; number+=1){
      while(fgets(string, STRING_LEN, fp1)){
          data = strtok(string, ","); 
          if(i == number){
          //  printf("%s\n", data);
              strcpy(first[number], data);
          }
          i++;
          number++;
      }

      r = strcmp(first[number], first[number+1]);
      if(r>0){
          strcpy(s, first[number]);
          strcpy(first[number], first[number+1]);
          strcpy(first[number+1], s);
      }
      printf("\nSorted array\n");
      for(i=0; i<=number; i++){
          puts(first[i]);
      }
  break;
 }
```

Comment: Use a well-known sorting algorithm.  [This one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/) should suffice.  The C code there is perfectly serviceable; all you should have to do is replace the integer assignments with their `strcpy` equivalents.

Comment: Your outer `for` loop does not anything; it runs once. A general comparison sort algorithm necessarily has **two** nested loops while you have *0*...

Comment: Consider calling `qsort()`.

Comment: ... which is defined in header file `<stdlib.h>`  Documentation for `qsort()` is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort).

Comment: The question is very much like a series of questions such as this [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64301575/how-to-arrange-data-in-file-in-c) by a user whose name apppears in the data of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things.

Try reading the contents of the file, and store the string of each line in a string array. Then sort the array, e.g. by using bubblesort.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STRING_LEN 200

void sort_strings(char arr[][STRING_LEN], int n);

int main(){
  char str[STRING_LEN], records[5][STRING_LEN];
  char * pch;
  FILE * fp1 = fopen("file.csv", "r");
  int count = 0;

  while(fgets(str, STRING_LEN, fp1))
  {
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
    pch = strtok(str, ",");
    strcpy(records[count++], pch);
  }
  printf("Before:\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    printf("%s\n", records[i]);
  sort_strings(records, count);
  printf("\nAfter:\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    printf("%s\n", records[i]);
 return 0;
}

void sort_strings(char arr[][STRING_LEN], int n)
{ 
    char temp[STRING_LEN]; 
  
    // Sorting strings using bubble sort 
    for (int j=0; j<n-1; j++) 
    { 
        for (int i=j+1; i<n; i++) 
        { 
            if (strcmp(arr[j], arr[i]) > 0) 
            { 
                strcpy(temp, arr[j]); 
                strcpy(arr[j], arr[i]); 
                strcpy(arr[i], temp); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
Before:
Bilal Khan
Ali Ahmed
hello
darth

After:
Ali Ahmed
Bilal Khan
darth
hello
```

I didn't use `qsort()` since I imagine you are doing this for practice.

Relevant links: [Sort with bubblesort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-strings-using-bubble-sort-2/) and [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input).

---

Edit with using `qsort()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
int compare(const void * a, const void * b);

int main(void)
{
  ...
  qsort(records, count, sizeof(records[0]), compare);
  printf("\nAfter:\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    printf("%s\n", records[i]);
 return 0;
}

int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return strcmp(a, b);
}
```

Output:

```
Before:
Bilal Khan
Ali Ahmed
hello
darth

After:
Ali Ahmed
Bilal Khan
darth
hello
```

Comment: I don't know how `qsort` works if you can do it. I am working on a project. It's not a practice.

Comment: @QuoraBai post updated, I think now it answers your question! :)